# How to return early pattern for functions?

Tags: javascript, return-value

Modify the function such that it returns "undefined" when the function calls back (-2,2)

```
function abTest(a, b) {

return Math.round(Math.pow(Math.sqrt(a) + Math.sqrt(b), 2));
}
abTest();
```

Comment: Please format your code properly and explain what you have already attempted.

Comment: Note: The downvote you received (not from me) likely happened because you did not show much effort.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the square root of a negative number in JavaScript should already be returning `NaN`.  But, here is one way you may check the result of the calculation, and then return a custom string `undefined` in this case:

```js
function abTest(a, b) {
    var result = Math.round(Math.pow(Math.sqrt(a) + Math.sqrt(b), 2));
    return !isNaN(result) ? result : "undefined";
}

console.log(abTest(2, 2));
console.log(abTest(-2, 2));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function abTest(a, b) {
  if (a < 0 || b < 0) {
    return;
  }
}
abTest(2, 2);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation for your code rather than posting code only. Additional explanation will be more helpful .

Answer (score 0):

Since javascript square root of a negative number as NAN .You can use the below function to check if any of the passed argument is negative number. If any of the number is negative you can return "undefined".

```
function abTest(a, b) {
    return  (a<0 || b<0) ? "undefined" : 
     Math.round(Math.pow(Math.sqrt(a) + Math.sqrt(b), 2));  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, while returning an undefined value you don't need to define the word "undefined" as it is a keyword. It simply takes a return keyword with a semi-colon as defined below, rest is just the logic according to the requirement:

```
if (a < 0 || b < 0)
{
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function abTest(a, b) {
  if (a < 0 || b < 0) return undefined;
  return Math.round(Math.pow(Math.sqrt(a) + Math.sqrt(b), 2)); 
}

abTest(2,2);
```